# R- assign inside a function

Tags: r, function, assign

I need to create a data frame from a function entering another data frame name and reshaping the data. The issue comes when I need to named the output after a transformation of the input table name.
My code so far is:

```
tablaXYZ<-data.frame(a=seq(1,2,1), 'X1'=seq(2,3,1), 'X2'=seq(3,4,1))
rownames(tablaXYZ)<-c('X1', 'X2')
```

And the function I worte is:

```
creaMelts<-function(tbl){
    library(reshape2)
    texto<-deparse(substitute(tbl))
    tbl2<-melt(tbl, id.vars=rownames(tbl))
    texto2<-substr(texto,4,nchar(texto))
    colnames(tbl2)<-c('userId','movieId', texto2)
    tblName<<-paste0('df', texto2)
    print(paste('tblName', tblName, ' '))
    assign(tblName, tbl2)
    return(assign(tblName, tbl2))
}
```

When I run:

```
creaMelts(tablaXYZ)
```

I get:

```
"tblName dflaXYZ  "
```

So, considering "assign" works returning in the object given in the 2nd place with the name stored in the object in the 1st place, like:

```
 `m<-'hola'`
 assign(m, tablaXYZ)
```

And then I ask for m, I get:

```
"hola"
```

But if I ask for "hola" I get the table:

```
hola
   a X1 X2
X1 1  2  3
X2 2  3  4
```

I thought I would have a data frame named  "dflaXYZ" with the values:

```
  userId movieId laXYZ NA
1      2       3     a  1
2      3       4     a  2
```

But if I run:

```
 dflaXYZ
```

I only get:

```
"dflaXYZ"
```

and if I run for example:

```
a<-creaMelts(tablaXYZ)
```

And then ask for "a", I get the desired table.

```
  userId movieId laXYZ NA
1      2       3     a  1
2      3       4     a  2
```

I need to get the same table but named in this case `dflaXYZ` (deleting the 1st 3 letters and adding `df` to the input table name).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We need to use `envir` argument for the `assign` to access the environment outside the function.

```
creaMelts<-function(tbl){
   library(reshape2)
   texto<-deparse(substitute(tbl))
   tbl2<-melt(tbl, id.vars=rownames(tbl))
   texto2<-substr(texto,4,nchar(texto))
   colnames(tbl2)<-c('userId','movieId', texto2)
   tblName<<-paste0('df', texto2)
    print(paste('tblName', tblName, ' '))
    assign(tblName, tbl2, envir = parent.frame() )

 }

creaMelts(tablaXYZ)
dflaXYZ
#  userId movieId laXYZ NA
#1      2       3     a  1
#2      3       4     a  2
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I need to use it in a list of tables, I'm trying with obj<-lapply(lista,creaMelts) where lista=list(tbl1, tbl2, ...) and it's not working. Do you know why it's not possible to use this function inside a loop? Should I write another question for this? Thanks.

Comment: @GabyLP Instead of `parent.frame` use `.GlobalEnv` because the `lapply` is another environment which is the parent.frame of the function.

Comment: Still got issues. This part: texto<-deparse(substitute(tbl))
is printing "X[[i]]", so I'm not getting any table.

Comment: @GabyLP  That is a different question because your function was about `assign`