# How to make a function to create a customised pie chart? (problems in inputing the argument)

Tags: r, function, arguments, pie-chart

I am new to R (pretty much one week of coding so far). My apologies for the simple question. I am trying to write a simple function that will create a pie chart dependent on the variable of the dataset I want to input.

The dataset is

```
ID<-c("001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008","009","010","NA","012","013")
Name<-c("Damon Bell","Royce Sellers",NA,"Cali Wall","Alan Marshall","Amari Santos","Evelyn Frye","Kierra Osborne","Mohammed Jenkins","Kara Beltran","Davon Harmon","Kaitlin Hammond","Jovany Newman")
Sex<-c("Male","Male","Male",NA,"Male","Male",NA,"Female","Male","Female","Male","Female","Male")
Age<-c(33,27,29,26,27,35,29,32,NA,25,34,29,26)
data1<-data.frame(ID,Name,Sex,Age)
```

The code that works without the function is:

```
#calculation of counts
dSex <- data %>%
  filter(!is.na(Sex)) %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  mutate(Total = sum(Count), Percentage = round((Count/Total),3))

## Compute the position of labels
dSex <- dSex %>% 
  arrange(desc(Sex)) %>%
  mutate(ypos = cumsum(Percentage)-0.5*Percentage)

dSex %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=Percentage, fill=Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="White") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = paste0(round(Percentage*100,0),"%\n(", Count, ")")), color = "white") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#7e0f7e", "#026b6c")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Sex")) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    axis.text = element_blank() 
  )
```

So I started to write the function and I am already struggling. I would like to input the variable Sex in the name of a new data I would call "dSex" but, I don't think it is working. I put the line with deparse() and substitute() because my understanding is that it helps R to understand that "Var" is the argument of the function. And I also put double "{" "}" but it does not seem to read it!

```
FctPieChart <- function(dat,Var){
  
  Var <- deparse(substitute({{Var}}))
  
  dVar <- dat %>%
    filter(!is.na({{Var}})) %>%
    group_by(Var) %>% 
    summarise(Count = n()) %>%
    mutate(Total = sum(Count), Percentage = round((Count/Total),3))
}  
FctPieChart(data,Sex)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `!is.na(c("{", " {", " Sex", " }", "}"))`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 13 or 1, not size 5.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Also another quick question, the pie chart I drew is quite big, is there a way to reduce the size?

Thank you very much in advance, if someone has any idea, this would really help me!

Best regards,

Stephanie

ANSWER BASED ON SUGGESTION BELOW:
The answer was to input the variable (here: `Sex`) in character as an argument of the function and use the function `get()` whenever I would call the variable in the function. get() would allow me to transform the characters into the variable. However, the use of the  funtion `get()` created a change in the name of the variable: " `get(Var)` ". I solved the issue by renaming the variable in the data and by creating a copy of the first variable Var as `Var2`.

I also wanted to get the actual data that stopped being created once it was in a function (it was being created in the code that was not in function). I found that `dVar <<- dVar` would solve the problem because it would create the data. The data would be called  `dVar` and the name does not depend on the variable inputed (in the old code it was `dSex`)

Since I wanted the name of the table to be reflective of the variable used (instead of a regular "dVar"), I solved the issue by renaming it by using the function assign() and the `envir=`.

The corrected code is below:

```
FctPieChart <- function(dat,Var){

#Create a replacement of  `get(Var)`  to use later
Var2 <-Var #We will use this one later instead of Var since Var is going to be changed into something else
print(Var2)

#Frequencies table
dVar <- dat %>%
filter(!is.na(get(Var))) %>%
group_by(get(Var)) %>% #changes the name of the column to "`get(Var)`"
summarise(Count = n()) %>%
mutate(Total = sum(Count), Percentage = round((Count/Total),3))

#Position calculation for the Pie Chart
dVar <- dVar %>%
arrange(desc(`get(Var)`)) %>%
mutate(ypos = cumsum(Percentage)-0.5*Percentage)   print(dVar)

#Rename the variable that was changed in the data 
colnames(dVar)<-c(Var2,"Count","Total","Percentage","ypos") 
print(dVar)

#Make the graph
Graph <- dVar %>% 
ggplot(aes(x="", y=Percentage, fill=get(Var2))) +#fill=`get(Var)`)  #get(Var2) alloWs to transform character into variable
geom_bar(stat="identity", color="White") +
coord_polar("y", start=0) +
geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = paste0(round(Percentage*100,0),"%\n(", Count, ")")), color = "white") + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#7e0f7e", "#026b6c")) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(title = Var2)) + #title = Var2 takes the value as characters of Var2 
theme(
axis.title = element_blank(), 
axis.line = element_blank(), 
axis.text = element_blank() 
)
print(Graph)

#Create the table
dVar<<-dVar

#Change name of the data based on the variable 
assign(paste0("d",Var2),dVar,envir = parent.frame()) #use envir = parent.frame() to access the environment outside the function, source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296670/r-assign-inside-a-function
rm(dVar,envir = parent.frame())
}
FctPieChart(data,"Sex")
```

I would like to thank @Silentdevildoll who helped me solve the problem.

Have a good day!

Stephanie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used something like this before, and there is certainly a flaw in my code, but this was my attempt at trying to help you out. I'm sure others will have a better solution, but this is a start at least:

```
FctPieChart <- function(dat,Var){
  
  dVar <- dat %>%
    filter(!is.na(get(Var))) %>%
    group_by(get(Var)) %>%
    summarise(Count = n()) %>%
    mutate(Total = sum(Count), Percentage = round((Count/Total),3))
  
  dVar <- dVar %>%
    arrange(desc(`get(Var)`)) %>%
    mutate(ypos = cumsum(Percentage)-0.5*Percentage)
  print(dVar)
  dVar %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x="", y=Percentage, fill=`get(Var)`)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="White") +
    coord_polar("y", start=0) +
    geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = paste0(round(Percentage*100,0),"%\n(", Count, ")")), color = "white") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#7e0f7e", "#026b6c")) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Sex")) +
    theme(
      axis.title = element_blank(), 
      axis.line = element_blank(), 
      axis.text = element_blank() 
    ) 
  
}  
FctPieChart(data1,"Sex")
```

I'm not really familiar with the deparse(substitute) that you used, but I know `get()` is a way to turn a string into a variable, so essentially I replaced the Var in the first paragraph of your function to get(Var). Where I'm sure this isn't ideal however, is that it the `group_by(get(Var))` changes the name of the column to `get(Var)`, which I demonstrated by printing the table. Note that I also input the variable as "Sex" instead of just Sex. Like I said, this isn't perfect, but I think this maybe can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much! Yes, it is a start and it draws the pie chart! Yes, it is a shame it is changing the name of the column to get(Var). I have two questions: 1) Do you know why it is not creating the table "dSex"? I need it because I would like to print it when I knit it. 2) Also, when do you know when to write " ` get(Var) ` " or "get(Var)"? Again thank you so much! You showed me the light at the end of the tunnel!

Comment: For number 2), I understand now. It is like you said, after the paragraph of code, it transforms the variable into ' ` get(Var) ` '.

Comment: Thank you @Silentdevildoll for helping me solve the issue